# Python: get last non zero elem from factorial(N)

Tags: python

I need to create a function, where I should get the last non zero digit of `N!`.

The following code returns an incorrect answer.

```
def get_last_nonzero_elem(n):
    if 0 <= n <= 1000000:
    factorial = reduce(lambda x, y: x * y,[1] + range(1, n+1))
    list_factorial = map(int, str(factorial))
    for i in reversed(list_factorial):
        if i != 0:
            return i
else:
    return None
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Expected input and "wrong" output ?

Comment: @Jarvis wrong output

Comment: @PetrPetrov No, dude, what do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: What input are you giving and what output are you getting, what is your expected output. Because this program is working well according to your requirement .

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare there are specify that input is a file where `0 ≤ N ≤ 10^6` and output file with one digit - last non zero

Comment: Compute factorial using arrays, your given method won't be able to calculate factorial of a huge number. @PetrPetrov

Comment: Try to run this `reduce(lambda x, y: x * y,[1] + range(1, 1000000+1))` in terminal see how much time it's taking to find factorial so this is not the right method to find out

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the factorial, just do this :

```
a = str(factorial)
output = int(a.replace('0', '')[-1])
```

Assuming your `n` is not too large for its factorial to be stored in an `int`. Otherwise, use `lists` to compute factorial of huge numbers.

Answer (score 0):

See this code:

```
def fact(n):
    if n==0:
            return 1
    else :
            return n*fact(n-1)


x = fact(44)    # x =2658271574788448768043625811014615890319638528000000000L
y=str(x)[::-1] # convert x to string and invers it
str(int(y))[0]  # convert y to int after to string and get the first char 
#8
```

Answer (score 0):

No recursion limit, low memory usage, with this one:

```
from functools import reduce

def fact(n):
    if n==0:
        return 1
    else :
        # in python 2 replace range by xrange:
        return reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, range(1, n+1))

def last_non_zero(n):
    while n:
        d = n%10
        if d!=0:
            return d
        else:
            n //= 10

N = 1000
f = fact(N)
print("factorial of {} is : {}".format(N, f))
print("last non zero is:", last_non_zero(f))
```